# Invalid Expression Term in If...Else Statement C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, visual-studio-2012

While trying to make a `console` application in `VSL studio 2012` that outputs advice on what to wear, depending on the temperature inputted by the user, I am running into the error

> "Invalid Expression Term"

on every else if statement I have in this code. I have no idea as to what I am doing wrong here.

If someone could point me in the right direction of resolving this issue, that would be amazing!
Thank you

```
if (temp <= 40)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" It is very cold. Put on a heavy coat.");
}
else if (temp > 40 && <= 60)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is cold. Put on a coat.");
}
else if (temp > 60 && <= 70)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The temperature is cool. Put on a light jacket.");
}
else if (temp > 70 && <= 80)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The temperature is pleasent. You can wear anything you like");
}
else if (temp > 80 && <= 90)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" The temperautre is warm, you can wear short sleeves.");
}
else (temp > 90)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is hot. You can wear shorts today.");
}
```

Comment: If should be e.g. `temp > 40 && temp <= 60`

Comment: Are you allowed to have a condition after the else keyword?

Answer (score 5):

This is not valid syntax:

```
else if (temp > 40 && <= 60)
```

You need to do this:

```
else if (temp > 40 && temp <= 60)
```

Comment: such a large oversight by me... Thank you for pointing out that out.

Answer (score 2):

You have written invalid expression:

```
(temp > 40 && <= 60)
```

Correct format:

```
(temp > 40 && temp <= 60)
```

Please correct all invalid expressions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this large oversight by me.

Answer (score 0):

Like Erik said, you have to "repeat" the variable to do another comparison.
You cannot either put "else" followed by a boolean expression(else should be just "else {}"), you should put if after else, like that:

instead

```
else (temp > 90)
```

use

```
else if (temp > 90)
```

So, your entire code should be:

```
if (temp <= 40)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" It is very cold. Put on a heavy coat.");
            }
            else if (temp > 40 && temp <= 60)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is cold. Put on a coat.");
            }
            else if (temp > 60 && temp <= 70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The temperature is cool. Put on a light jacket.");
            }
            else if (temp > 70 && temp <= 80)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The temperature is pleasent. You can wear anything you like");
            }
            else if (temp > 80 && temp <= 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" The temperautre is warm, you can wear short sleeves.");
            }
            else if (temp > 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is hot. You can wear shorts today.");
            }
```